# Link List: show list in physical and logic order in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to get my link list to show the numerical variables in numerical order. I know I need to set another void but I am lost to set it in numerical order. Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct node
{
    int number;
    node *next;
};
bool isEmpty(node *head);
char menu();
void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, int number);
void insert(node *&head, node *&last, int number);
void remove(node *&head, node *&last);
void showList(node *current);
void showLogic(node *current);

bool isEmpty(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

char menu()
{
    char choice;
    cout << "Menu\n";
    cout << "1. Add an item.\n";
    cout << "2. Remove an item.\n";
    cout << "3. Show the list Physically.\n";
    cout << "4. Show the list Logically.\n";
    cout << "5. Exit.\n";

    cin >> choice;
    return choice;

}

void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, int number)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->number = number;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    last = temp;
}

void insert(node *&head, node *&last, int number)
{
    if (isEmpty(head))
        insertAsFirstElement(head, last, number);
    else
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->number = number;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}

void remove(node *&head, node *&last)
{
    if (isEmpty(head))
        cout << "The list is already empty.\n";
    else if (head == last)
    {
        delete head;
        head == NULL;
        last == NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void showList(node *current)
{
    if (isEmpty(current))
        cout << "The list is empty\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "The list contains: \n";
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            cout << current->number << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

void showLogic(node *current)
{

}

int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node *last = NULL;

    char choice;
    int number;

    do
    {
        choice = menu();
        switch(choice)
        {
        case '1': cout << "Please enter a number: ";
                  cin >> number;
                  insert (head,last,number);
                  break;
        case '2': remove(head,last);
                  break;
        case '3': showList(head);
                  break;
        case '4': 
            break;
        default: cout << "System Exit\n";
        }
    }
    while(choice != '5');

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you going to accomplish this without sorting?  You need to sort the list in some fashion.

Comment: That is why I am asking how to sort void showList(node *current) numerical order in void showLogic(node *current).

Comment: So your question boils down to "how do I sort a linked list"?  I'm sure there are tons of hits on SO.  The simplest thing to do is to copy the numerical values from the list into an array, sort the array, and display the array.

Comment: Is `head` & `last` are still NULL when you use it in `insert()`.

Comment: Not sure where you are looking at?

Comment: PaulMckenzie - I have been looking for a solution or an example of the my problem but have come up with nothing. If you can point me in the right direction or show how to numerically sort the list that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to sort the linked list.  The easiest way to do that is to take the values in the list, store them in a container, and sort the container.  Since you're not allowed to change the order of the nodes (keep the physical order), maybe this is the best bet as far as showing a sorted list.

First, traverse the list from head to tail -- your showList() function does much of this work already.  However, instead of showing each node, place the data for that node in a container (a dynamic array, vector, or a simple array).  If it's a simple array, make sure you have room for all the elements, and keep track of the number of elements.

Then you take the container, and use any number of sorting algorithms to sort -- the simplest is the bubble sort.  Then you display the sorted container to the user.

So to sum up, you are actually not changing the linked list, or even using the linked list to a great extent.  All you're doing is gathering up all of the data in each node, placing it in an container, and then all the real sorting work shifts from the linked list to the container.

Comment: Okay, but in code format, how would I do that? I know what you are saying but I am having difficulties in creating the code to produce the list logically.

Comment: Please start simple.  First write a function that goes through each node in the linked list and adds it to vector using push_back().  Inspect that vector to see if it gathered all of the integers after the loop.  Then you are three or four lines of code away from finishing the work (if you're allowed to use std::sort).  If not, then create another small application that sorts numbers in an array.  Take what you learned from that app and apply it to this larger application.